# Does anyone have a sample for RadPieChart for nativescript + angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm creating a cross-platfrom app that has to display a PieChart on my home tab. Where can I find a complete example?

I try to follow [this tutorial](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/professional-ui-components/ng-Chart/Series/pie) changing it based on the version I'm using but doesn't work and in my opinion the first part doesn't match the second part.

This is a part of ***home.component.html***

```
<RadPieChart id="pieChartGiacenze" allowAnimation="true">
            <RadPieChart.series>
              <DonutSeries
                  selectionMode="DataPoint"
                  expandRadius="0.4"
                  outerRadiusFactor="0.7"
                  innerRadiusFactor="0.4"
                  valueProperty="Amount"
                  legendLabel="Brand"
                  [items]="pieSource">
              </DonutSeries>
            </RadPieChart.series>
            <RadPieChart.legend>
              <RadLegendView position="Right" offsetOrigin="TopRight" width="110" enableSelection="true"></RadLegendView>
            </RadPieChart.legend>
          </RadPieChart>
```

and this is a part of ***home.component.ts***

```
public pieSource;

//.....somecode.....

this.pieSource = new ObservableArray();
      this.pieSource.push({Brand:"ciao", Amount:50});
      this.pieSource.push({Brand:"mondo", Amount:80});
```

I can't see the chart in my home. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Where did you take that template from? As far as I can remember, the professional UI of nativescript is made by telerik, so you may want to check their examples, like this one: https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/blob/master/chart/app/examples/behaviors/chart-behaviors-chart-pie-selection.component.html

Comment: I got it from the nativescript docs at this [link](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/professional-ui-components/ng-Chart/Series/pie). 
I try to use the template that you gave me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample, in .html file

```
<GridLayout height="500" rows="auto,*">
                <Label text="Test Pie Chart" row="0"></Label>
                <RadPieChart allowAnimation="true" row="1">
                    <PieSeries tkPieSeries selectionMode="DataPoint"
                        expandRadius="0.4" outerRadiusFactor="0.7" [items]="pieSource"
                        valueProperty="Amount" legendLabel="Brand"></PieSeries>
                    <RadLegendView tkPieLegend position="Right" offsetOrigin="Bottom"
                        width="100" enableSelection="true" offsetOrigin="TopRight"></RadLegendView>
                </RadPieChart>
            </GridLayout>
```

and in your .ts file

```
pieSource: { Brand: string, Amount: number }[] = [
        { Brand: "Audi", Amount: 10 },
        { Brand: "Mercedes", Amount: 76 },
        { Brand: "Fiat", Amount: 60 },
        { Brand: "BMW", Amount: 24 },
        { Brand: "Crysler", Amount: 40 }
    ];
```

Here is the [playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=KGYjKN) for you.

Comment: It works but I can't see the chart, I only see the legend. Do you know what could it be?

Comment: Have you imported the module in your Ngmodule?

Comment: I've imported `NativeScriptUIChartModule`

Comment: which platform and device are you testing ?

Comment: I'm testing the app on an android device in particular on an Asus ZenFone Z00ED and on a Samsung Galaxy S7

Comment: Now I tested the app on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 10.1 and it's the same, the chart isn't show

Comment: Can you create a playground with your code? May be something is wrong with your code

Comment: This is the [Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=QVYErQ)

Comment: There was the problem with your layout. I have updated the playground https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=QVYErQ&v=2

Comment: Thank you! It works!! I've another question, how can I change the palette of the chart?

Comment: How did you make it work? can you add sample code

Comment: I'm having the same issue, Piechart won't render in the android but works fine in iOS